# Ubuntu wont allow me to open a server using python3

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, ubuntu

I've been having this problem for a couple weeks now and it's been causing me lots of stress in some of my classes. I have been using Ubuntu to use Python 3 to open a local server. I've tried using "sudo" and I still get access denied. I've asked professors for help but they have no idea whats wrong either. I had it work once and then after that it never worked again. Here is the error I keep getting.

`____@DESKTOP-55VJC61:/mnt/c/Users/Julia/Desktop/p5/empty-example$ python3 -m 
    http.server
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 1221, in <module>
        test(HandlerClass=handler_class, port=args.port, bind=args.bind)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 1194, in test
        httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 440, in __init__
        self.server_bind()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 138, in server_bind
        socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 454, in server_bind
        self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

If anyone has a solution to this problem please help!

Comment: Can you attach the python code you are running that generates these errors?

Comment: It is looks like your user denied to open socket. For example it is situation when your from ordinary user try to run `python3 -m http.server 80` - the result will be the same, because by default only root can bind socket to ports below 1024. Try to do it again but from root (`su -` command)